# How to make sprites fit the entire screen of more than one device

Tags: coronasdk, sprite-sheet, texturepacker

I been working with corona for a few and I wanted to know how to make a sprite (using texture packer) and set it as a background of my app. I also want it to fit as many devices as it can without any of the sprite content being cropped out. In short, I want the sprite to be a background fitting the entire screen without losing any of the sprite's content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this help you:

```
local _W = display.actualContentWidth
local _H = display.actualContentHeight

local bg = display.newImage( 'bg.jpg' )
bg.x, bg.y = display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY


local mode = 'inside'

-- the image will fill the device width/height exactly
if mode == 'stretch' then
    bg.width, bg.height = _W, _H

-- the image will be scaled proportionally to fit inside the device width/height
elseif mode == 'inside' then
    local scale = math.min( _W / bg.width, _H / bg.height )
    bg:scale(scale, scale)

-- the image will be scaled proportionally to completely fill the area, 
-- allowing portions of it to exceed the bounds defined by device width/height
elseif mode == 'outside' then
    local scale = math.max( _W / bg.width, _H / bg.height )
    bg:scale(scale, scale)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Could you please explain your code so I get what it does ?

Comment: Load an image (bg.jpg) and set to center position. Change de mode and see the results ('stretch', 'inside' or 'outside'):

- stretch: the image will fill the device width/height exactly;
- inside: the image will be scaled proportionally to fit inside the device width/height;
- outside: the image will be scaled proportionally to completely fill the area, allowing portions of it to exceed the bounds defined by device width/height.